# How do I override DataContext.SubmitChanges()?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I want to override the SubmitChanges() method for my model.

Whern I try to override I get a compiler error:

> cannot override inherited member
>   'System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()'
>   because it is not marked virtual,
>   abstract, or override

Is there anyway I can override this?  Or do I have to create another method that runs my code and then runs the base SubmitChanges()?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't override the [parameterless overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292162.aspx), but you *can* override [the one taking a `ConflictMode` parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345081.aspx).

It's not *documented* that the first just calls the second with an appropriate conflict mode, but that's certainly what I'd expect.